# Static variables together with command line

Tags: java, command-line, static, cmd, arguments

I currently got a class like:

```
public class SQL {
    private final static String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private final static String USERNAME = "secret";
    private final static String PASSWORD = "secret";
    private final static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://secret:3306/secret";

    private static BasicDataSource basicDataSource = null;

    public static void init() {
        basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
        basicDataSource.setUrl(URL);
        basicDataSource.setUsername(USERNAME);
        basicDataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        basicDataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1;");
        basicDataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        basicDataSource.setTestOnReturn(true);
        basicDataSource.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        try {
            basicDataSource.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (basicDataSource == null) {
            init();
        }
        try {
            return basicDataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new IllegalStateException("bf4.sql.SQL.getConnection: No connection could be made: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use command line arguments (my main method is located somewhere else) to set the `static` variables and call that with a `.bat` file for different configurations.

Now I am wondering: **What is the best solution for this?**

I have also thought up some solutions myself:

- Make the `static` variables `non-final` and then set them directly after `main()` has been called, prior to further execution of the program and thus also prior to any calls to the `SQL` class.
- Make the `static` variables `non-final` and then try to set them in a `static` block via a `Scanner` on `System.in`.

I'm thinking to go with solution #1, but are there any downfalls to it. I'd like to hear comments on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to inform you that your class is *not thread safe*. I would suggest you not to keep any static variables in the `SQL` class as they are not actually `static` logically.

Create a class something like

```
class SQLConfiguration{

    private String userName;
    ....
}
```

Now this `SQLConfiguration` instance can be read from any source be it properties file or xml or scanner you just create the instance of it and pass it to the `SQL` class while initialization.

```
class SQL{

    public static synchronized init(SQLConfiguration sqlConfiguration){
        //init in a thread safe manner
    }

}
```

I feel the best way to implement your requirement is a [Multiton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)

```
public class SQLMultiton{
    private static final Map<Object, SQLMultiton> instances = new HashMap<Object, SQLMultiton>();

    private SQLMultiton() {
        // no explicit implementation
    }

    public static synchronized SQLMultiton getInstance(SQLConfiguration key) {

        // Our "per key" singleton
        SQLMultiton instance = instances.get(key);

        if (instance == null) {
            // Lazily create instance
            instance = new SQLMultiton();
            instance.init();  
            // Add it to map   
            instances.put(key, instance);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    // other fields and methods ...
}
```

Comment: That would require then that I would **need** to call `SQL.init()` prior to using `SQL.getConnection()` rather than doing it the lazy way and let `SQL.getConnections()` be allowed to `init` itself in case I would have forgotten. Means a little rewrite, but this should improve it.

Comment: Yes you can of course do lazy initialization, but SQL needs to know whom to connect to and you should pass configuration to `getConnections()` method.

Comment: I'm afraid the updated answer is beyond my scope, as my programs (up till now) only use one `BasicDataSource` that connects to only one `(host, database, username)` pair. I have read up on synchronization a little bit more now, and I see that I do need to synchronize `SQL.init()`, but do I also need to synchronize `SQL.getConnection()`?

Comment: No that doesn't have to be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a properties file

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {
           //load a properties file
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));

           //get the property value and print it out
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Of course in your case you want to set the values of the properties file to your variables (which will need to be non-final)